# Get not matching record as null while joining two queries

Tags: sql-server

I have two queries having same columns, 1 returning 3 rows and other returning 2 rows. While I join this two query I am able to get only 2 rows. How can I get three rows with not matching record as null in sql server?

Query1:

```
Select UDA.production_date_T, Count (WO.order_state) AS 'cntplan' 
From WORK_ORDER WO 
INNER JOIN UDA_Order UDA ON UDA.object_key = WO.order_key 
group by UDA.production_date_T) TBL1
```

Query2:

```
Select UDA.production_date_T, Count (WO.order_state) AS 'ACTUAL' 
From WORK_ORDER WO 
INNER JOIN UDA_Order UDA 
ON UDA.object_key = WO.order_key 
WHERE WO.order_state = 'BOOKED' 
GROUP BY UDA.production_date_T
```

My desired Output is:

```
production_date_T           cntplan     ACTUAL
2019-04-26                       22         4
2019-05-03                        4        NULL
2019-09-05                        19        0
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to DBA.SE! Do you by any chance also have the table definitions and some sample data?

Comment: Hi @RandiVertongen, The sample data is: table 1 returns output : production_date_T            cntplan
2019-04-26                        22
2019-05-03                       4
2019-09-05                       19  and my query2 returns output: production_date_T             ACTUAL
2019-04-26                        4
2019-09-05                              6

Comment: Have you considered using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN?

Comment: Please provide sample data as DML - also table data as DDL. p.s. welcome to the forum! 8-)

Comment: Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/238613/edit) your question when adding details. It's hard reading DDL or data from the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you just need to move the filter you are using in the second query as a CASE expression:

```
SELECT  UDA.production_date_T, 
        COUNT(WO.order_state) cntplan,
        SUM(CASE WHEN WO.order_state = 'BOOKED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ACTUAL
FROM dbo.WORK_ORDER WO 
INNER JOIN dbo.UDA_Order UDA 
    ON UDA.object_key = WO.order_key 
GROUP BY UDA.production_date_T
;
```